# Compare objects of Same class and store value in a List of another class

Tags: .net, class, c#-4.0

I want to compare two different objects of same class and store the value in a list of an another class.

It is working fine for basic data type but I am facing the problem when class contains property of a list or property of another class.

```
    class Program
    {
      static void Main()
      {
        SomeCustomClass a = new SomeCustomClass();
        SomeCustomClass b = new SomeCustomClass();
        a.CwNumber = "A";
        a.MaterialId = 1;
        a.MaterialName = "Material1";
        a.ListMyClass.Add( new MyClass1 { id = 11,Name="Name1" });
        a.ListMyClass.Add(new MyClass1 { id = 12, Name = "Name2" });

        b.CwNumber = "A";
        b.MaterialId = 2;
        b.MaterialName = "Material2";
        b.ListMyClass.Add(new MyClass1 { id = 21, Name = "Name3" });
        b.ListMyClass.Add(new MyClass1 { id = 22, Name = "Name4" });

        List<Variance> rt = a.GetDiffValue(b);       
      }

     public List<Variance> GetDiffValue<T>(this T val1, T val2)
     {
       List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
       Variance v = new Variance();
       PropertyInfo[] pi = val1.GetType().GetProperties();
       foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
        {
            Variance v1 = new Variance();
            if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType == true)
            {
                v1.Prop = p.Name;
                v1.valA = p.GetValue(val1, null);
                v1.valB = p.GetValue(val2, null);
            }
            else
            {
                v1.Prop = p.Name;
                v1.valA = p.GetValue(val1,null);
                v1.valB = p.GetValue(val2,null);
            }
            if (!v1.valA.Equals(v1.valB))
            {
                variances.Add(v);
            }
        }
        return variances;
      }
    }

    public class SomeCustomClass
    {
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public string CwNumber { get; set; }  
        public List<MyClass1> ListMyClass { get; set; }
        public UsesModel Uses { get; set; } 

        public SomeCustomClass()
        {
            ListMyClass = new List<MyClass1>();
        }
     }
     public class MyClass1
     {
        public int id;
        string Name;
     }      

    public class Variance
    {
      public string propertyName { get; set; }
      public object OldValue { get; set; }
      public object NewValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: There are so many classes in your code that I can't understand what you're asking. Can you provide a much more simplified code snippet?

Comment: @IlyaKogan I have edited the code.Please check  if it makes any sense now.

Comment: It's still unclear which classes your question refers to. The question says something about "same class" and "other class" and it's really hard to understand which classes these are.

Comment: if I have a class named  "SomeClass" then I want to compare "SomeClass Object1" and "SomeClass Object2 " and I want to store the value in a List of a second class say "DifferenceClass". like List<DifferenceClass> DifferenceValueByField=Difference(Object1.Object2).The "DifferenceClass" may have three fields-- i. FieldName , ii. Value of Object1.Fileld_N and iii. Value of Object2.Fileld_N

Comment: It will be much clearer if you edit the question instead...